# Делаю веб-приложение на Django с формами

Tags: html, python, django, веб-программирование, views

Ниже прилагается код расширения html шаблона в котором я и прописываю форму, код urls.py и код views.py. При запуске веб-приложения выдает ошибку, что 'key_url' (то, что прописываю в action тега forms) not found: "Reverse for 'key_url' not found. 'key_url' "

**list.html:**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Хрен {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form action=" {% url 'key_url'%}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.key }}

    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py (именно конкретно этого приложения, а не общий для проекта):**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'Factory'
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.KeyAction.as_view(), name = 'key_url'),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Key, Value
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import KeyForm

class KeyAction(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = KeyForm()
        return render(request, 'Factory/list.html', context= {'form':form})
```

Comment: `KeyForm` что из себя представляет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте 'Factory:key_url'. Указав app_name ваши URL'ы имеют пространство имен